Can't deploy a python server and mosquitto broker
I have this Dockerfile:
# Use the official python image
FROM python:3.12

# set the working directory
WORKDIR /app

# copy the current directory contents into the container at /app
COPY . /app

### install libgl
RUN apt update && apt install -y libgl1-mesa-glx && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
# install the required packages
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt


# run the server script
CMD ["python", "server.py"]

and i have this docker-compose.yml file:
version: '3'

services:
  mqtt2:
    image: eclipse-mosquitto:latest
    ports:
      - "1883:1883"
      - "9001:9001"
    volumes:
      - ./mosquitto.conf:/mosquitto/config/mosquitto.conf:ro

  server:
    build: .
    depends_on:
      - mqtt2
    environment:
      - MQTT_BROKER=mqtt2
    links:
      - mqtt2

and this is my mosquitto.conf:
listener 1883
allow_anonymous true
listener 9001
protocol websockets

and this is my server.py file:
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
import time
import os


MQTT_BROKER = os.getenv('MQTT_BROKER', 'mqtt2')
MQTT_PORT = 1883
#MQTT_PORT = 9001
CAMERA_TOPIC = "camera/image"
CLIENT_TOPIC = "server/message"


def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc, properties):
    print("connected with result code " + str(rc))
    client.subscribe(CAMERA_TOPIC)


def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
    print(f"Recieved message on {msg.topic}")
    processed_message = "new message for testing"
    client.publish(CLIENT_TOPIC, processed_message)


client = mqtt.Client(mqtt.CallbackAPIVersion.VERSION2)

client.on_connect = on_connect
client.on_message = on_message

client.connect(MQTT_BROKER, MQTT_PORT, 120)
client.loop_start()
try:
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    client.loop_stop()
    client.disconnect()

when i build the docker file locally, it works, but when i want to deploy it to a server, it gives error. the error is related to this line of python code:
client.connect(MQTT_BROKER, MQTT_PORT, 120)

It says: """Name or service not known.""" what should i do? what is wrong with my codes?
As i said, i tried to build this dockerfile locally with this command:
docker-compose up --build

it works, but when i want to deploy it to a server, i get this error:
"""Name or service not known."""


The links: option is related to an obsolete Docker networking setup, and it's not at all required.  Does deleting this option make any difference?

And have you added something to log the MQTT_BORKER and MQTT_PORT values to be sure they are set to what you expect? Also just checking you have included the required bits in the mosquitto.conf so it's listening on more than just  127.0.0.1 (which iirc doesn't existing in a container... so the mosquitto container might not actually be running)

@DavidMaze i deleted that but it didn't make any difference
